# Date Filter in SSRS 2008

Tags: datetime, dataset, ssrs-2008, filtering

I am working with SSRS 2008. I have a table in my report consisting a date/Time Column (DOB). I have a date/time parameter (MyDate) as well. I am trying to set a Filter on my data set like

```
FormatDateTime(Fields!DOB.Value,2)<=FormatDateTime(Parameters!MyDate.Value,2)
```

It doesn't filter my table correctly. But if I remove FormatDateTime function then it works fine. i want to understand whats the problem here.

Comment: Do you really want to compare the date only, not the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatDateTime` will return a string, so you're not comparing dates anymore but rather their string representations.

Comparing the dates `02-Feb-2012` and `10-Oct-2012` will give different results than comparing the strings `2/2/2012` and `10/10/2012`.

As mentioned in the comment, it looks like you're just trying to remove the time portion from dates?

Something like this should work, i.e. converting the strings back to dates.

```
CDate(FormatDateTime(Fields!DOB.Value,2)) <= CDate(FormatDateTime(Parameters!MyDate.Value,2))
```

But this is just one suggestion, there are any number of ways of doing this.

Comment: Man, it's interesting how this SSRS questions look a lot like limbo. Not even the OPs bother choosing the answer. :D  Good answer, that's what I was going for as well.

Comment: @Ian Preston : I got it working in the same way as you have suggested.